# How to change installshield name at the end of sdLicense dilogue

Tags: installshield, installshield-2009

At the left corner of SdLicense Dilogue one masked text will come as "InstallShield" how to change the text from where it is rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to InstallShield, they do not allow the text to be changed. See Q105444:
https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/FAQ/Q105444